# Prove that if the reminder of the division W(x) / (x-a) = n, then W(a) = n

Tags: polynomials

I've always taken this property for granted. Only recently have I begun to wonder why this property actually works. 
Could you give me some hints how to prove it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem#Proof

Answer (score 3):

This is really just the definition of "remainder".

The division algorithm tells us, under these conditions, that there is some polynomial $p(x)$ such that $$W(x)=p(x)(x-a)+n$$  If we now take $x=a$ we get $$W(a)=0+n=n$$